# Wrong display order of figures and text

Tags: floats, positioning

Why do the figures appear **BEFORE** instead of **AFTER** the section title ???

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper,english,dutch,leqno]{article}

\usepackage[top=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1.5cm,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,patterns,calc}
\usepackage[heightadjust=all]{floatrow}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}

\begin{document}

\section*{Why is this section title BELOW the figures ???!!!}

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
\draw[line width=1mm,rotate=45] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}}
{\caption{\footnotesize\bf Figure 1.}
\label{fig:_____}}
\hspace{0cm}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
\draw[line width=1mm] (0,0) circle (3);
\end{tikzpicture}}
{\caption{\footnotesize\bf Figure 2.}
\label{fig:_____}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

The figures should appear between the section title and THIS line !!!

\end{document}
```

Comment: `figure` is a float... so it moves around, either on the current page, or to following pages.

Comment: The following might be a duplicate: [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279/5764) Please give some feedback.

Comment: Moreover, there is the ultimate go-to: [How to influence the position of float environments like `figure` and `table` in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764); [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/5764)

Comment: can we vote to close as a duplicate of the links that @Werner provided? Please let us know :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Figure environment "floats" to find an optimal position on the page. When you begin a figure, you can use the options [htbp!] to specify whether the figure should go "here", the "top" of this page, the "bottom" of this page, or a special "page" reserved for floats. LaTeX, in its infinite wisdom, will sometimes prevent you from putting a figure in an "ugly" place, but you can (sort of) override its decision using the "!" option. When you haven't used any option, the environment assumes that you provided [tbp], and it's choosing to put the figure at the top of the page, above where your section goes. So using

```
\begin{figure}[bp!]
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: For 'prevent' read 'discourage'; there is always the `[H]` option provided by the [float package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float).

Comment: Only \begin{figure}[h!] fixed my problem. THX !

Comment: @IanThompson on `H` a comment on a question earlier today: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74993/using-includegraphics-before-my-new-line-of-text-but-on-pdf-image-is-after-the/74994#comment160156_74993

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- indeed. I just wanted to point out that it is not impossible. Anyway, it's not as if I created the thing!

Comment: Wow! it works perfectly. Thanks Mark!